# PyMongo - MaxDistance operation working but results are not as expected

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, pymongo

I have following pymongo query to retrieve geoNear data from MongoDB( 3.0). "distance" is passed in kms and I understand from MongoDB documentation that the "maxDistance" has to be in meters, so I am using "distance * 1000" in my query

```
 def getNearestVoices(self, longitude, latitude, distance, userid=None, count='500'):
            response = []
            for doc in self.users.aggregate([{"$geoNear": {"near": [longitude, latitude],
                                                           "distanceField":"distance",
                                                           "maxDistance": (distance * 1000),
                                                           "distanceMultiplier": 6371,
                                                           "num": int(count),
                                                           "spherical": True}}]):

                    pass
```

Now when I pass "1" for distance my expectation is to return "distance" which matches 1 KM or less but this is not happening and all records are returned.

I also noticed one thing, when I change the "distance * 1000" to "distance / 1000" in my mongo query, then I get less records but still not matching my expectation.

I am not able to figure out what's wrong in my query.

PS: I am using distanceMultiplier 6371 to retrieve my output in kms

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
"maxDistance": (distance * 1000)"
```

to

```
"maxDistance": (distance / 6371)
```

worked for me. Since I am using distance multiplier, I think I have to factor it in